# Kali linux username/password bypass

Tags: linux

I forgot my user name and password to my Kali Linux OS. How do I bypass or reset my username and/or password for Kali Linux. I have not tried anything because I am new to this software, so I do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root (or boot into single-user mode).

Then you can simply change the user password with `passwd <user>` (where `<user>` is replaced with the actual user name).